# Resetting a oneWay property on Ember

Tags: forms, ember.js, data-binding

Is there any way of resetting a oneWay computed property to its associated property?

```
...
outOfSyncWidth: Ember.computed.oneWay 'model.width'
...
```

The problem comes when I change this property inside a form control and I want the controller which manages the form to be able to reset this property so that it can show the `model.with` property.